# How to save cv.Mat to to local as png in opencv.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, opencv, backend, tesseract

```
const roiList = [];
      finalContours.forEach(con => {
            const x = con[3].x;
            const y = con[3].y;
            const w = con[3].width;
            const h = con[3].height; 
            // console.log('x: ' ,x, 'y: ', y, 'w: ', w,'h: ',h )
            const roiRect = new cv.Rect(x, y, w, h);
            const roi = new cv.Mat(image, roiRect);
            // const roi = cv.getRegion(image, new cv.Rect(x, y, w, h));
            roiList.push(roi); 
      });
for (let i = 0; i < roiList.length; i++) {
        // Save roi as PNG to temp directory<br/> 
    const imagePath = path.join(tempDir, 'OutputImageOptions', `roi_${generateUniqueId()}.png`);
    cv.imwrite(imagePath, roiList[i]);
    const result = await Tesseract.recognize(imagePath, 'eng', { tessjs_create_hocr: '1', preserve_interword_spaces: 1,tessedit_char_blacklist: '!@#$%^&*()-_=+{}[]:;"\'|<>,.?/~`\n', });
}
```

Want to save roiList which is cv.Mat to local pc then use Tesseract recognize the text.

How to save cv.Mat locally as png in opencv.js?

Error:

> TypeError: cv.imwrite is not a function

Comment: go via `<canvas>`